# macOS: Implementing something similar to the Add App Link in Notes of macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, hyperlink

Starting with macOS 13 Ventura, Apple has added a button to the Notes app toolbar that allows you to quickly insert Links and [Universal Links](https://developer.apple.com/ios/universal-links/) to notes that are present in other apps like Safari or Messages.

[image: App Link in Notes]

I wonder if there is a public API behind it. At first I thought it is backed by the [SharedWithYou Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sharedwithyou), but that only seems to work with links that are associated with your app via Universal Links. I'm especially interested in getting links from websites shared with uses in Messages or opened in Safari.

Comment: So you want to know the exact code of the public API, or how it generally works?

Comment: I’d like to implement the same Apple Notes feature you can see in the screenshot in one of my apps. If there is a public API, great as there does not seem to be a way to read links from other sandboxes apps without user interaction.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately I'm not entirely sure how to implement the same feature you want, only provide some details.

You should try and read [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing-apps-and-websites-to-link-to-your-content?language=objc) from apple.

They recommend the usage of [the following for macos](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/3172702-open?language=objc) for opening one or more URLs asynchronously in the specified app using the provided options.

```mac
open(_:withApplicationAt:configuration:completionHandler:)
```

where the declaration is:

```mac
func open(
    _ urls: [URL],
    withApplicationAt applicationURL: URL,
    configuration: NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration,
    completionHandler: ((NSRunningApplication?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil
)
```

You can find what to enter in the second documentation link as they have labelled code with links in them.

Now the main part is you want your app to be able to access universal links, so you can follow [this documentation on supporting universal links in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-universal-links-in-your-app).

To support universal links in your app (from documentation):

1. Create a two-way association between your app and your website and specify the URLs that your app handles. See [Supporting associated domains](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode/supporting-associated-domains).
2. Update your app delegate to respond when it receives an `NSUserActivity` object with the `activityType` set to `NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb`.

To update your app delegate to respond to a Universal Link - an example code shows how to handle a universal link in macOS:

```mac
func application(_ application: NSApplication,
                     continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                     restorationHandler: @escaping ([NSUserActivityRestoring]) -> Void) -> Bool
{
    // Get URL components from the incoming user activity.
    guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
        let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL,
        let components = NSURLComponents(url: incomingURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
        return false
    }

    // Check for specific URL components that you need.
    guard let path = components.path,
    let params = components.queryItems else {
        return false
    }    
    print("path = \(path)")

    if let albumName = params.first(where: { $0.name == "albumname" } )?.value,
        let photoIndex = params.first(where: { $0.name == "index" })?.value {            
        print("album = \(albumName)")
        print("photoIndex = \(photoIndex)")
        return true  

    } else {
        print("Either album name or photo index missing")
        return false
    }
}
```

[Another article by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html) which you can follow to see how to support universal links.

### NOTE:

Universal links can be for messages too! This is because it uses an `apple-app-site-association` file to support universal links. Universal links was made to access between apps too.

As for how you want to access recent links, e.g. links that are open in apps currently, I'm not too sure at the moment.

Comment: Thank you. That function lets you open urls. But what I want is to have a list of useful links the user may wants to work with. Links that are open in other apps like browsers, messages or a link that has been mailed to you recently.

Comment: @Daniel hmm that will also have to based on opening URLs and accessing them! I'll try to make my answer better though!

Comment: @Daniel So you want to access links that are open and recently used?

Comment: Yes that’s what I want 

Comment: @Daniel Hmm, at the moment I have found no answer, you can probably easily do so using ICloud or something to access any open links in apps currently, but all I can provide you is some examples of universal links which can support nearly anything (Note they are slightly different than urls and can access app links)